# how to reduce lookup time in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading a very large file from SSD (Solid State Device) which has integers stored in it.

```
int main () {
  string line;
  srand (time(NULL));

  set<int> vec;
  for(unsigned long int j=0; j<1342177280; ++j){
     i = rand() % 10 + 1; //although my code performs something complex, for simplicity I am taking random numbers.
     vec.insert(i);
  } 

  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int sum=0;
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      int i=atoi(line.c_str());
      if(vec.count(i))
            sum+=i;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Since vec is a very large set, so vec.count(i) is taking maximum time for me. Is there some way by which I may reduce the time of lookups (vec.count(i)) in my code. If yes, then can someone please guide me as to how can I achieve the same?

I am using gcc version 4.8

Comment: You could try using a `std::vector` rather than a `std::set` and make sure its elements remain sorted and unique manually.

Comment: You might also consider switching to a std::unordered_set

Comment: @Galik Are lookups faster in vector then set. I though since set is sorted, therefore lookups will be faster in it (due to binary search)

Comment: @StegVerner You can use `std::binary_search`.

Comment: @Cyber Are lookups faster in unordered_set then set. I though since set is sorted, therefore lookups will be faster in it (due to binary search)

Comment: @Galik Yes but if my vector is unsorted then how can I use binary search. Can you please explain with a small example

Comment: I'm just suggesting you do some tests. Vectors play well with CPU caching so they can be faster.

Comment: @Garlik I thought set will result in O(log n) comparisons and vectors will result in O(n) comparisons. And since my set is big, therefore it can not fit in the cache

Comment: I don't understand your example. Your set will only contain 10 numbers. Did you mean to add `j` rather than `i` to the set? Also, the `unordered_set` suggestion is a good one

Comment: Are you sure this works?  `sum += vec`  (sum is `int` and vec is `set`) ?  Did you profile your code?  What compiler options are you using (-O3?) ...  Most likely reading the file is taking longer than the set lookup unless you have more than let's say 2^50 elements in the set...

Comment: Why would you call a `std::set<T>` `vec`? Even in a testcase?

Comment: This is not a C++ question. It is a maths/algorithms question.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit By that logic, everything is Maths question... Isn't it?

Comment: Ditch `atoi`.  `strtol` is a complete replacement with better error handling.

Comment: Also, in your example code, `vec` is not a "very large set".  It almost surely contains all of the numbers 1-10, and never contains any others.  How large is the range of values in your real problem?

Comment: You may be able to use `std::bitset` (or `std::vector<bool>`) which both have `O(1)` element access with a very small proportionality constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using a `std::vector`. I wrote a special `insert()` function that makes sure the `std::vector` stays unique and sorted:

```
// unique, sorted inserts
void insert(vector<int>& v, int i)
{
    // find insert position in sorted order
    auto found = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), i);

    // avoid duplicates
    if(found == v.end() || *found != i)
        v.insert(found, i);
}

int main () {
  string line;
  srand (time(NULL));

  vector<int> vec;
  for(unsigned long int j=0; j<1342177280; ++j){
     int i = rand() % 10 + j; //although my code performs something complex, for simplicity I am taking random numbers.
     insert(vec, i); // use our special insert() function
  }

  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int sum=0;
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      int i=atoi(line.c_str());
      // binary search has O(log n) complexity
      if(std::binary_search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), i))
            sum+=i;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

The reason `std::vector` might give you better performance than a `std::set` is that vectors play well with CPU caches because they are stored in contiguous memory. So even if the vector is larger than the CPU cache it will still benefit as the cache loads the vector in chunks.

**EDIT:**

In my tests (using only 100000000 numbers) the vector consistently outperformed the set:

```
   sum              time
v: 2121140014233422 11.1849 secs
s: 2121140014233422 15.2953 secs

v: 2121140014233422 11.2197 secs
s: 2121140014233422 15.0505 secs

v: 2121140014233422 11.1063 secs
s: 2121140014233422 14.9652 secs
```

Comment: A surprisingly sane use of vectors for such a task, with a reasonable rationale. I wouldn't actually do this unless I _measured_ a substantial performance gain across my expected inputs, but certainly worthwhile considering it. Good job.

Comment: You should consider merging the two binary searches (std::binary_search and std::lower_bound). No reason to do the work twice.

Comment: You could replace `binary_search` in `insert` with `found != v.end()`.

Comment: @nwp Yes indeed. Thnx, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use set, use find method. Its complexity is logarithmic.

```
if(vec.find(val) != vec.end())
    //val is there in set
```

Comment: Yeah, so is `.count`'s. Your suggestion is literally identical to the OP's existing approach. -1

Comment: 4 more to go until what?